# how to fill the missing zero values with it's adjacent mean values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem but I was not able to write any code. I don't know how to approach this problem. So that's why I'm not posting the code. If anyone can help please do.

Assume I've some data like below,

```
my_list = [[0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 2, 0, 0], [1, 3, 4, 5, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I'm trying to fill the zeros with average values like smoothing operation.

Let's take first inner-list `[0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 2, 0, 0]`

1) First `0` can be filled with `(nonzero-left_bound, non-zero right_bound) / no of values)`. This has no left bound because it's the first number in the list, right bound with nonzero-value is 1. So, `(0+0+1)/3 = 0.3` now fill all the three values with 0.3 then the inner list will be

```
[0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 2, 3, 4, 0, 2, 0, 0]
```

2) Filling the middle zero values: `(4+0+2)/3 = 6/3 = 2.`

```
[0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0]
```

3) Filling last two zero values with `(2 + 0 + 0)/3 = 2/3= 0.6`

```
[0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6]
```

Similarly, fill all the remaining zeros for each inner list.

Comment: How do we handle cases like `4, 0, 2, 0, 0`? In your example, the `2` remains as a `2`, despite that it should be changed to `0.6` with the two zeroes after it?

Comment: I think OP means that only the zeros get replaced with new values

Comment: @user_6396 I was asking because in your first example you replaced a `1` with `0.3`.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Sorry my mistake. I've updated the question. I also need to change the non zero value (which is used to fill the zero value).

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Here in `[4, 0, 2, 0, 0]` first `(4 + 0 + 2)/3 = 2` then fill the all three values with 2 `[2,2,2,0,0]` and then `2+0+0/3 = 0.6` and fill all three values with `[2, 2, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6]`

Comment: To me, dividing by 3 feels weird and should be by 2, since you're taking the mean of the 2 "adjacent values".

Comment: I think you might be looking for something like [interpolate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) of pandas library.

Comment: @IMCoins I'm dividing it with 3 because we are applying the resultant values for all three values right. Can you post an example on how to do it using pandas iterpolate. I have not used it before. Is my result possible with pandas interpolate?

Comment: It will put the value in between. Meaning, if you have a 0 between a 2 and 3, it'll become 2.5. I don't understand for what purpose you'd need to add the 0 to the equation.

Comment: @IMCoins I'm sharing the values between three values right. Even 0 will get replaced with the result. That's why I'm dividing it by 3. So result will be`[1.6, 1.6, 1.6]` rather than `[2.5, 2.5, 2.5]`. If we can do your method (i.e divide by 2) using interpolate can you please post the solution as a answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought I would try my hand at this. Here goes:

```
def smooth(ls):
    left = 0
    for right, e in enumerate(ls):
        if e and ls[max(right - 1, 0)] != 0: # ignore consecutive nonzeros
            left = right
        if (e and left != right) or (not e and right == len(ls) - 1): # e is nonzero with zero(s) before it, or is last trailing zero
            avg = round((ls[left] + ls[right]) / (right - left + 1), 2) # 2 decimal places
            for ptr in range(left, right + 1): # flatten from 'left' to 'right', inclusive
                ls[ptr] = avg
            left = right # move up the left index to the last changed item
    return ls
```

Essentially, what the function does is it traverses the list once with two index variables, `left` and `right`. Every time there is a nonzero entry with a zero before it, a "flattening" is performed on the range of entries in positions `left` to `right`, inclusive. Then, the `left` pointer is moved up to the last changed index, and the process continues until the end of the list is reached.

The output for the first one matches that of Green Cloak Guy's program. The second one is slightly different, as his uses the original values from the list and mine does not.

```
>>> list(map(smooth, [[0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 2, 0, 0], [1, 3, 4, 5, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0]]))
[[0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 2, 3, 2.0, 2.0, 0.67, 0.67, 0.67], [1, 3, 4, 2.67, 2.67, 0.67, 0.67, 0.67, 0.67]]
```

I had it round to two decimal places in the example, but that can be easily changed if desired.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please add some comments it's hard to understand what's actually going on.

Comment: @user_6396 I have added some comments and simplified the code a bit. Is it easier to understand now?

Comment: There's still some lines I was not able to understand can you please include a few more `detailed` comments in the code.

Comment: @user_6396 If you are able to let me know which lines are unclear, then I can address those directly. Are there some specific ones you have in mind?

Comment: It's just that I was able to understand what was actually happening below(i.e other answer) due to more detailed comments. I was able to grasp what it was doing. I was hoping you could also provide a little more detailed comments on what it is actually doing. It's fine if you aren't able to provide more docs.

Comment: @user_6396 Okay, I understand. I have written a general outline of what the code does, and simplified it quite a bit.

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty naive and kind of messy implementation but it should do what you want. There are a lot of edge cases here that need to be taken care of, unfortunately, which is where most of the mess comes from.

```
# create a new list to hold our modified sublists
smoothed_list = []
# do for each sublist of my_list
for lst in my_list:
    # we'll be building a new list manually out of element from the old list.
    # this is too complicated to do in a list comprehension, unfortunately.
    new_lst = [lst[0]]
    # The number of contiguous zeroes we've seen
    zero_ct = 0
    # the last nonzero element that we saw
    last_nonzero_element = 0
    # step through this list one element at a time
    # I'm iterating by index instead of by element so that I can check for the last element
    for idx in range(1, len(lst)):
        elem = lst[idx]
        # If the current element is zero, then just add to the zero count.
        # note that if the last element is zero, we would end up with the wrong-size list
        # therefore we must take the other branch no matter what on the last element of the list
        if elem == 0 and idx < len(lst) - 1:
            zero_ct += 1
        # Otherwise, we either resolve the recent chain of zeroes, or just
        # add the current element to the new list.
        else:
            # If this is the first nonzero value in a while, or if this is a zero
            # at the end of the list that we need to resolve
            if zero_ct > 0 or (elem == 0 and idx == len(lst) - 1):
                # calculate the average of the range between last nonzero value and this value
                avg_to_replace = (last_nonzero_element + elem) / (zero_ct + 2)
                # remove the last element of new_lst, and replace it with the average we calculated
                # also add all the elements we've skipped so far, as well as the current element
                new_lst = new_lst[:-1] + [avg_to_replace] * (zero_ct + 2)
            else:
                # just add this nonzero element to the list
                new_lst.append(elem)
            # since we hit a nonzero element, reset the zero count and last_nonzero_element
            zero_ct = 0
            last_nonzero_element = elem
    # append our newly-created smoothed list to the list of smoothed lists.
    smoothed_list.append(new_lst)
```

When applied to the `my_list` given in your example:

```
my_list = [
           [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 2, 0, 0], 
           [1, 3, 4, 5, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0]
          ]
```

this gives the following:

```
[
 [0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333, 2, 3, 2.0, 2.0, 0.6666666666666666, 0.6666666666666666, 0.6666666666666666], 
 [1, 3, 4, 2.6666666666666665, 2.6666666666666665, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75]
]
```

You'll note that, in the second example, this uses the *original* value of the list to calculate the average, when that original value would have been changed by an earlier replacement (the fourth-to-last element in the second list would have been `2.66` after the other replacement, and thus the last four elements would have all been `0.66`. Instead, the program behaves as though it was still 3 when calculating the average). This is kind of a difficult bug to fix, and you'd have to decide which behavior you prefer.

I'll leave "getting rid of the decimal precision" as an exercise to the reader.